# SharePoint Online - unable to query against ArticleStartDateOWSDATE

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

Environment: SharePoint Online
Case: Define result source for using in content search web parts filtering publishing pages by Article Date (Managed property ArticleStartDateOWSDATE). The query text is:

```
ContentType:"My content type" AND (ArticleStartDateOWSDATE:{Today-10}..{Today}) {searchTerms?}
```

If we query by Created, then results are returned.
We've tried creating a new managed property with enabled Searchable and Queryable settings with no success. Any ideas?

Read resources (some of the fixes are not applicable because we are running in the cloud):

- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103435/sp2013-managed-property-articlestartdateowsdate-is-text-type
- http://www.slideshare.net/mikaelsvenson/sp-connections-query-rules-explained
- http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2013/07/problem-in-kql-with-date-times-and.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On the managed properties page, type in "Refinable" and you'll get a list of placeholder managed properties that you are allowed to customize.
2. Pick an available managed property, such as **RefinableDate00**, and click "*Edit/Map Property*" in the dropdown.
3. Under "*Alias*", add **ArticleStartDate** as the value
4. Select "*Include content from the first crawled property that is not empty, based on the specified order*".
5. Click "*Add a Mapping*" and page over until you find the crawled property **ows_q_DATE_ArticleStartDate**. Select this property and click OK.
6. For the date range portion of your expression, use the expression **ArticleStartDate>={Today-10}**

For further reference, check out https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-the-search-schema-in-SharePoint-Online-d4fab46d-ba41-4c03-9d4c-32b5b33198b6?CTT=1&CorrelationId=61fcc271-6284-4e99-9eab-1f2405dfdf29&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US for a full list of the steps required to add such Managed Property Aliases.

Comment: Thanks Keith,

The part with adding an alias to the property and issuing library reindex did the the trick. I have gone through a similar procedure without adding an alias, but it did not work for some reason.